# How to check Android NFC Card Emulation Mode is enabled

Tags: android, nfc

I am working with Android HCE Service, so I need to check 'Card Emulation Mode' is enabled.

I can check NFC normal mode is enabled by below code.

```
public static boolean isNFCon(Context context)
{
    NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
    NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();

    return (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled());
}
```

Therefore, I would like to know how to check Card Emulation Mode is enabled

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to check 'Card Emulation Mode' is on.

Android API only provides a method to check NFC is on or off.